# Falling over when item does not exist in list how to check

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq query but its falling over when no gender has been set against the user it says squencce

```
List<StandardLookUpList> _AnalsisCodes = GetAnayalsisCodesForExportCode();

var codesForThisItem = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode);
if (codesForThisItem.Count()  > 0 )
{
     if (codesForThisItem.First(x => x.code == Constants.Sport) != null)
      sport = codesForThisItem.First(x => x.code == Constants.Sport);

       if(codesForThisItem.First(x => x.code == Constants.Gender) !=null)
       gender = codesForThisItem.First(x => x.code == Constants.Gender);
}
```

I thought that this line was enough to fix this?.

```
if (codesForThisItem.First(x => x.code == Constants.Sport)
```

But its actually the code for this item is failing I cant use count to strap that as it may have the other codes held against it what is my best way of trapping if its not in the list replace with null string instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead and then check whether the result is null before proceeding. The problem with what you've written is that `.First()` always expects there to be a matching result:

```
List<StandardLookUpList> _AnalsisCodes = GetAnayalsisCodesForExportCode();
var codesForThisItem = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode);

if (codesForThisItem.Any())
{
     var sportResult = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Sport);
     if (sportResult != null) sport = sportResult;

     var genderResult = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Gender); 
     if (genderResult != null) gender = genderResult;
}
```

In fact, if it's always OK for `sport` and `gender` themslves to potentially be null (I don't know what they're set to before this code runs or what rules you have about them), you could just do:

```
List<StandardLookUpList> _AnalsisCodes = GetAnayalsisCodesForExportCode();
var codesForThisItem = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode);

if (codesForThisItem.Any())
{
     sport = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Sport);
     gender = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Gender); 
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer - it reuses the result of the predicate.  Nice!

Comment: @Scott Thanks. Looking at your version I think there's a chance of running the same query twice, obviously is not efficient, unless EF is smart enough to cache the result

Answer (score 1):

Use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`.  First will throw an exception (Sequence contains no matching element) when your predicate does not match any elements.

```
List<StandardLookUpList > _AnalsisCodes = GetAnayalsisCodesForExportCode();

var codesForThisItem = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode);
if (codesForThisItem.Any())
{
    if (codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Sport) != null)
    {
        sport = codesForThisItem.First(x => x.code == Constants.Sport);
    }

    if (codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Gender) != null)
    {
        gender = codesForThisItem.First(x => x.code == Constants.Gender);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` statements are useless, unless I'm missing something. Just use `FirstOrDefault` when doing the assignment.

Comment: @MariusBughiu In this case, `sport` and `gender` may already have values set elsewhere in the code.  OP only wants to update them if their predicate matches.  I totally agree, but that would be an additional change beyond the simple fix.